# Displaying a Random Word From Array in Two Spots

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, random

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="myFunction();" />
<div id="message">
    <p></p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="message">
    <p></p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var myarray= new Array ("Drama", "Fable", "Fairy Tale", "Fantasy", "Fiction", "Folklore", "Historical Fiction", "Horror", "Humor", "Mystery", "Mythology", "Poetry", "Realistic Fiction", "Science Fiction", "Short Story", "Tall Tale");

        var random = myarray[Math.round(Math.random() * (myarray.length - 1))]

        var display = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
    }
</script>
```

I have this so far and what I'm trying to do is have one button click display two random words from my array next to each other. Thanks in advance for the help!

https://jsfiddle.net/edexxmjo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a posible solution

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Search</button>
<div id="message1">
</div>
<br>
<div id="message2">
</div>
```

This is javascript

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = selectedWord();
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = selectedWord();
}

function selectedWord(){
    var myarray = new Array("Drama", "Fable", "Fairy Tale", "Fantasy", "Fiction", "Folklore", "Historical Fiction", "Horror", "Humor", "Mystery", "Mythology", "Poetry", "Realistic Fiction", "Science Fiction", "Short Story", "Tall Tale");

    return myarray[Math.round(Math.random() * (myarray.length - 1))];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` is unique, if you need to display in two spots either use `class` selector or add another unique `id` as like below,

```
<div id="message">     
</div>
<br>
<div id="message_2">      
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var myarray= new Array ("Drama", "Fable", "Fairy Tale", "Fantasy", "Fiction", "Folklore", "Historical Fiction", "Horror", "Humor", "Mystery", "Mythology", "Poetry", "Realistic Fiction", "Science Fiction", "Short Story", "Tall Tale");

    var random = myarray[Math.round(Math.random() * (myarray.length - 1))]

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
    document.getElementById("message_2").innerHTML=random;
    }
</script>
```

[To Get Elements by ID, Tag, Name, Class, CSS Selector](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html)